# It is possible for a foreign key to store values that aren't matching primary key values?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

Database design question. Let's say I have two tables: [PEOPLE] and [FRUITS]:

```
[PEOPLE]
- id
- fruit_id
- many other columns

[FRUITS]
- id
- name
- many other columns
```

Which are related by PEOPLE.fruit_id = FRUITS.id.

So fruit_id can store any value from id of [FRUITS] table. But the problem is, I want fruit_id to store values besides those, like 'All of the fruits', 'Some of the fruits', 'None of the fruits'.

I already used NULL as a flag for 'None of the friuts' value.

What is the best solution in this situation?

And out of curiosity I wanna ask: What to do in the situation when I want one foreign key to store values of multiple primary keys? For example: there is one more table [VEGETABLES]:

```
[VEGETABLES]
- id
- name
- many other columns different from [FRUITS]
```

And I want PEOPLE.fruits_id to be able to store values from both FRUITS.id and VEGETABLES.id.

I am not native English speaker, so forgive me for mistakes.

Comment: Consider redesigning your db to have a junction table relating people to fruit and forgetting about storing a value for none, some or all - you can work this out on selection.

Comment: Foreign keys are constraints and are used for referential integrity they don't 'store' anything and they cannot reference more than 1 table.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the fruit_id within the people table allows you to assign one or none (NULL) fruit to a person.
If you want to assign several fruits to one row in the people table you need a pivot table (one to many)

e.g

```
PEOPLE_FRUITS
- people_id
- fruit_id
- unique key people_id, fruit_id
```

This way you can assign none, one or many fruits to a row in the people table.
The unique key would disallow assignment of the same fruit to the same person multiple times.

Same applies to vegetables

Comment: This answers second question, thanks. But I don't want to assign several fruits to one row in the first question. I just want to assign a flag instead of a fruit that will mean 'All of the fruits'. WAIT, I just realized something. I can just make a row in the table [FRUIT] that will have name 'All of the fruits' and problem solved :) But is it right thing to do?

Comment: @Norwak no, this is not really a good idea. 1) makes querying for specific fruits more difficult 2) when you add a new fruit, such a value will implicitly add the new fruit to those people that have this value.